# How to Query to get top two questions based on no of persons answered for each Sections

Tags: mysql

Hi I have table Answers where I store Section Code,Question,No of persons answered.

[See here for Structure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e997/1)

Now I want  highest answered two Questions for each section .

[See the result here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68e8c/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    SELECT * FROM answers a
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers b WHERE a.code = b.code AND a.`count` <= b.`count`
  ) <= 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2726a/10

If you want to get top 3,4,5, simple increase the number at the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

select question from answers order by noofpersons desc limit 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select top 2 a.code,a.ques,count(a.count) as mycount from answers a inner join answers b on a.code=b.code AND a.ques=b.ques group by a.code,a.ques
```